# Right click not working on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, right-click, jpopup

I have been working on how to enable the right click and show a popup menu it was asked earlier at [Enable right click in jFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198383/enable-right-click-in-jframe)
but it was not as useful actually my problem is that I am facing the left click as enable also my piece of code that I have been using is:

```
     private void jTextField1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
        if (!evt.isPopupTrigger()){
           p.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        }
     }
```

The problem is that the left mouse click is also popping up a menu. What I want is to just pop up the menu on the right click. Please suggest me a solution and the blunder I'm doing here Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you continue with your previous question ? Why did you accept an answer if it does not solve your problem ?

Comment: how can i continue with my previous attempt please let me know I'm sorry for this now topic @Apurv and Andrew Thompson

Comment: @user2277645 `The problem is that the left mouse click is also popping up a menu.` I can't believe, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JTextField and your definition for (empty)JPopupMenu

Comment: @mKorbel below is the solution mentioned for my problem thanks for your kind reply sir

Comment: @user2277645 I think that not (reason for my comment:-), this isn't about how the JPopup works :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code snippet will help you:

```
if (evt.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK){  
    //right click  
}
```

For further information see the [JDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) of `MouseEvent`.